# What does 'ls | sort file.txt' do?

Tags: pipe, ls, sort

I am just learning about shell commands; more specifically, I am learning about pipe.

Right now I cannot tell the difference between the following commands: `ls | sort file.txt` and `sort file.txt`. Apparently, there is supposed to be a difference.

Please can someone explain what is happening?

Comment: note that you shouldn't pipe the result of `ls`. See [Why *not* parse `ls` (and what to do instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/44425)

Comment: That's a hefty read, but I'll be sure to give it a gander. My question comes from an example I was looking at, so it wasn't any child of my thoughts. Thank you for he reply though :)

Comment: @JakeJackson: Hopefully it was an example of what not to do because that command doesn't actually work.  The output of `ls` is being discarded.

Comment: @jesse_b Yes, possibly. It asked what the difference was, but maybe they expected you to realise there was no difference. Either way, I understand now :)

Comment: Well there is a difference, `ls | sort file.txt` will spawn an extra process

Comment: Haha yeah, technically you're right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The visible outcome of the two commands `ls | sort file.txt` and `sort file.txt` would be the same:

`sort file.txt` sorts the lines of `file.txt` lexicographically and outputs the result.

`ls | sort file.txt` calls `ls` to generate a list of the names in the current directory.  That list is sent to `sort file.txt`.  Since `sort` is reading from `file.txt`, it will ignore the list of names coming from `ls` and instead produce the sorted contents of `file.txt` as output.  The output from `ls` is discarded since `sort` is not reading from its standard input in this instance.

You may have wanted to use `ls | sort` which would have sorted the lines of output from `ls` (which would have been sorted already).  `sort` would have read the output of `ls` since it was not given any specific filename to read from and is therefore reading from its standard input stream (which is connected to the output stream of `ls` via the pipe).  Note though that using a tool that expects lines of text may fail to handle Unix filenames as these may contain newlines.

Comment: Thank you, my friend. I thought it was a load of rubbish, the example I was pulling this from. Pipe is not hard to understand whatsoever, but the example I was following made me question it. At least I know that the command does literally nothing - what I thought ti begin with. I just want to check. Stay safe :)

Comment: Note that in `ls | sort file.txt`, the output of `ls` is not read at all. If `sort` exits before `ls` has finished writing, `ls` will be killed by a SIGPIPE. One visual difference with `sort file.txt` could be the eventual error messages if any displayed on stderr by `ls`.